# Magnific exclude link

Tags: javascript, html, magnific-popup

Is there a way to get Magnific Popup to ignore a link?

```
<div id="floor-plans">
    <a href="/path/to/image">Title goes here</a><a href="www.360tour.com">360 degree Tour</a>
</div>
```

I want to ignore the second link because it's a link to a popup window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you initializing Magnific Popup? If you specify a class on the `<a>` tags you want to be Popup-able, then you can use it as the selector when you initialize Magnific Popup. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="floor-plans">
    <a class="magnific" href="/image1">Title goes here</a><a href="...">Outside link</a>
    <a class="magnific" href="/image2">Title goes here</a><a href="...">Outside link</a>
    <a class="magnific" href="/image3">Title goes here</a><a href="...">Outside link</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".magnific").magnificPopup({type:'image'});
});
```

The links with the class `magnific` would trigger Magnific Popup, but no other links would.